# C2039: Class is not a member of Namespace

Tags: c++

**Mage/Interface/Context.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <Mage/Interface/Element.h>
#include <Mage/Renderer/RenderingContext.h>
#include <Mage/Renderer/VertexBuffer.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

namespace Mage {
    namespace Interface {
        class Context {

        protected:
            RenderingContext* ctx;
            VertexBuffer* vbo;
            glm::mat4 projection;
            Mage::Interface::Frame* uiParent;

        public:
            Context(RenderingContext* ctx);
            ~Context();

            void render();
            Mage::Interface::Frame* createFrame();
        };
    }
}
```

**Mage/Interface/Element.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#include <Mage/Interface/Context.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

namespace Mage {
    namespace Interface {
        class Element {

        protected:
            Mage::Interface::Context* ctx;
            std::vector<Element*> children;
            glm::vec3 position;
            float scale;

        public:
            virtual void draw();

            void attach(Element* child) {
                this->children.push_back(child);
            }

            inline glm::vec3 getPosition() {
                return this->position;
            }

            float getScale() {
                return this->scale;
            }
        };

        // Frame is an untextured, single colour quad. Frame may contain other
        // Elements.
        class Frame : public Element {

        public:
            Frame();
            Frame(glm::vec3 pos);
            Frame(float width, float height);
            Frame(glm::vec3 pos, float width, float height);
        };
    }
}
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
Error   C2039   'Context': is not a member of 'Mage::Interface' Mage2D  c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mage2d\include\mage\interface\element.h    14

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Mage2D  c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mage2d\include\mage\interface\element.h    14

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    Mage2D  c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mage2d\include\mage\interface\element.h    14

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Mage2D  c:\users\jesse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\mage2d\include\mage\interface\element.h    14
```

When I take out `Mage::Interface::Context* ctx`, the code compiles fine. I figured I must have missed a semi colon, but I can't see it - it all seems to check out just fine to me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. Element.h includes Context.h and Context.h includes Element.h, that's not going to work.

The way to solve that is to forward-declare types instead of including their headers whenever you can, it'll also reduce compile times.

Comment: Thank you. Literally the most unhelpful compiler error ever; you'd think it would be easy to print a message about a circular dependency.

Comment: Not really. The circular dependency is just your design problem. The compiler problem is the one it reported. You can have circular dependencies, though you need to handle them differently. You are yet to see *literally* unhelpful messages.

Comment: @luk32: After some of the horror stories I've heard about useless compiler errors, I am ready to believe you.

You're probably right, I tend to over zealously split classes into separate files.